# Rotativa: bootstrap classes ignored

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Using rotativa, I´m successfully generating a pdf from a partial view using ActionAsPdf. 
Problem:
The generated pdf seems to ignore bootstrap classes.
View:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex-column align-items-start">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">@Model.AssemblyOrderID</p>
                    <span class="font-weight-bold mb-1">@Model.Billing_Unit</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">@("Materialschein erstellt am " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    foreach (var article in Model.Articles)
    {
        <div class="container">
            <div class="flex-column align-items-start mb-4">
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <div>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">@("Benötigt: " + article.ArticleAmount + "x " + article.ArticleNumber)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="font-weight-bold">@("Fehlende Anzahl: " + article.ArticleAmountMissing)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The pdf just lists the lines, not formatting / aligning the content.
Inline css is recognized, but that is not what I want.
Google couldn´t help me. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
It seems like Rotativa can not load the bootstrap css. I tried loading it using Server.MapPath and using `<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css">` but that didn´t help. I also imported bootstrap.css in my default stylesheet (which is loaded correctly by Rotativa) but that didn´t help either.

**EDIT 02**
As requested here is the code which generates the pdf:

```
public ActionResult PrintPDF(string assemblyOrderID)
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("PrintableView", new { assemblyOrderID = assemblyOrderID });
}

public ActionResult PrintableView(string assemblyOrderID)
{
    var assemblyOrder = dataService.GetAssemblyOrderByNumber(assemblyOrderID);

    if (assemblyOrder != null)
    {
        var viewModel = new StuffNoteViewModel();

        viewModel.AssemblyOrderID = assemblyOrder.AssemblyOrder_PrefixLeft + assemblyOrder.AssemblyOrder_PrefixMiddle + assemblyOrder.AssemblyOrder_Number;
        viewModel.Billing_Unit = assemblyOrder.Work_Address.Billing_Unit;

        var articles = dataService.GetArticlesForAssemblyOrder(assemblyOrderID);

        if (articles.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var article in articles)
            {
                viewModel.Articles.Add(new AddArticleItemViewModel()
                {
                    ArticleAmount = article.Quantity,
                    ArticleAmountMissing = article.Quantity - article.OrderQuantity,
                    ArticleNumber = article.Article.Article_Number,
                    Short_Description = article.Article.Short_Description
                });
            }
        }

        return PartialView("~/Areas/AssemblyOrders/Views/Shared/Partials/AssemblyOrderStuffNote.cshtml", viewModel);
    }

    return null;
}
```

For example, if I create a view with a row and cols like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-6" style="background-color: lightcoral;">left</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-6" style="background-color: lightblue;">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The PDF looks like this... :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try and use as link to your css for bootstrap v3.3.7 the following:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

Use `col-sm` instead of `col-lg-6`.